# Unable to Store a Pig Relation using Parquet Storer

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, parquet

I am trying the below Pig statements in grunt shell.

pig version is --> Apache Pig version 0.12.1

```
grunt> register /home/user/surender/mapreducejars/parquet-pig-1.0.1.jar;
grunt> A = LOAD '/user/user/inputfiles/parquet.txt' USING  PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,name:chararray);
grunt> STORE A into '/user/user/outputfiles/pig' USING parquet.pig.ParquetStorer;                    
2016-09-27 07:09:18,509 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. parquet/io/ParquetEncodingException
```

Details at logfile: /home/user/surender/localinputfiles/pig_1474973730264.log

I want to know what went wrong here .Can someone help me on storing the pig relation using parquetStorage

Answer (score -1):

you need to add the parquet jar like parquet-pig-bundle-1.5.0.jar and register it by 
    REGISTER '/path_for_jar/parquet-pig-bundle-1.5.0.jar';

please check the link which explains about it.
Here's [a link](http://www.intelliwareness.org/2014/05/reading-and-writing-parquet-files-with-mortar/)!